# Docstrings when nothing is returned

Tags: python, function, return, docstring

What is the docstring convention when a function doesn't return anything?

For example:

```
def f(x):
    """Prints the element given as input

    Args:
        x: any element
    Returns:
    """
    print "your input is %s" % x
    return
```

What should I add after `Returns:` in the docstring? Nothing as it is now?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should use `None`, as that is what your function actually returns:

```
"""Prints the element given as input

Args:
    x: any element
Returns:
    None
"""
```

All functions in Python return *something*.  If you do not explicitly return a value, then they will return `None` by default:

```
>>> def func():
...     return
...
>>> print func()
None
>>>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly.  Do you mean if it is OK to just do `return` instead of `return None`?  Yes, that is fine.  Adding the `None` in that case is redundant.  It should be considered understood that Python functions return `None` if you do not return a value.

Comment: If you mean "is it wrong to omit 'Returns:' entirely from your docstring if you don't have any explicit return statements?", I tentatively say "no". [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) says to describe the return value "if applicable", so you could argue that you don't have to describe it if it doesn't matter.

Comment: @keyser - In addition to what Kevin said, the OP could be doing this for code analysis tools.  That, or he has to follow some convention set by his superiors (ugh.  I hate those ;)

Comment: @iCodez Yup, definitely :p Though they're there to prevent arguments :p. My main curiosity was mainly what PEP/people say/do. Also, thanks Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit it. And for simplicity and reduced noise you probably should omit it.

The docstring style you used is "Google Style" and the style guide says this about the `Returns` section:

> If the function only returns None, this section is not required.

https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#doc-function-returns