# NumPy docstring for function type and None type

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, docstring

I am writing the following function:

```
def parse_zip_file(path, handler):
    """
    Parse all files contained in a zip file (specified by the path parameter).

    Parameters
    ----------
    path : str
        The path to the zip file.
    handler: function
        When looping through all the files contained in the zip file, this method will be called every time
        a new file is found. Two arguments are passed. The first argument is the name of the discovered file
        and the second argument are the contents of the file.

    Returns
    -------
    None
        Nothing is returned.
    """
    return None
```

I was wondering, am I doing this correctly? Is there any way I can check the docstring is correct (I am using PyCharm as an editor)?
More specifically, is `function` the right type for the handler argument? Where can I find an overview of all NumPy docstring types I can use? And Is it correct that I use `None` if nothing is returned at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same question. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784179/docstrings-when-nothing-is-returned) is really similar, and the accepted answer says to include it, but doesn't really make a claim about why or why not to do it, nor does it answer your particular question about where to validate your work.

A high level answer to validating your docstrings is the [documentation](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) from NumPy.

---

That may be enough, but keep reading for answers to your micro-questions within this question. First:

> I was wondering, am I doing this correctly? Is there any way I can
> check the docstring is correct (I am using PyCharm as an editor)?

This [page](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html#docstring-validation-using-python) from NumPy has a good section on validation. You can do it with numpydoc.

> To see the Restructured Text generated for an object, the numpydoc module can be called. For example, to do it for numpy.ndarray, use:

```
$ python -m numpydoc numpy.ndarray
```

Other options, could use [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), another package is [pydocstyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle) - though I can't speak for its coverage it does look to be maintained, supporting through Python 3.9.

> More specifically, is function the right type for the handler
> argument?

I believe so, I don't see a specific part on which types are valid, I would assume all are valid, and, function is a valid type/class.

> Where can I find an overview of all NumPy docstring types I can use?

[Top level docs](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html).

> And Is it correct that I use None if nothing is returned at all?

**Yes**. The docs say the following, emphasis is my own:

> 5. Returns
>
> Explanation of the returned values and their types. Similar to the
> Parameters section, except the name of each return value is optional.
> **The type of each return value is always required**: