# Numpy Docstrings when nothing is returned

Tags: python, function, numpy, return, docstring

A very similar question is already asked here: [Docstrings when nothing is returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784179/docstrings-when-nothing-is-returned)

but I would like to ask the same question with Numpy Docstrings.

For example:

```
from typing import NoReturn

def stop() -> NoReturn:
    """

    Returns
    -------
    NoReturn
    """
    raise RuntimeError()
```

What is the most convenient way to write Numpy Docstring "no return" type?

Is it preferable using `void` or `-` or blank or maybe something else?

For your information nothing is detailed about this in https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#returns

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you just don't specify `Returns`, similar to how you don't use `Yields` if your function doesn't yield.

I tried looking for an example in the numpy source code but I didn't find one.